# What is the unit of distance returned by cv::flann::knnSearch?

Tags: c++, opencv, knn, flann

I am searching `k` nearest neighbors of `n` SURF descriptors. I compute the nearest neighbors by creating `cv::flann::index` object on the descriptor matrix.

```
cv::flann::Index index(desc,cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4));//cv::Mat desc: holds all the descriptors

index.knnSearch(centralDescriptor,indicesNN,distsNN,10);
```

After this I have to compare the returned distance of each nearest neighbor with the size of the central feature point. Now the problem is that the size of the central feature point is stored in its corresponding `cv::KeyPoint` and the unit of `cv::KeyPoint::size` is pixels where as the distances are all floating points and less that zero.

**Question: How do I convert the distance returned by the `cv::flann::knnSearch` to pixels or convert the `cv::KeyPoint::size` into the distance unit?**

I am sorry for the poor wording of the question, my English is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

cv::flann::knnSearch returns distance in SURF space, in other words, it is similarity between image patches (i.e. this corner looks more similar to this one, than to this blob). And distance between keypoints is just pixel distance (like use ruler on the monitor - for distance in inches).

Comment: I thought that knnSearch was returning normalized distance because SURF descriptors are normalized. Indeed if you display knnSearch distances, they are all between 0 and 1. So now the question is how compare normalized distance with normal distance or size?

Comment: Please, define what do you mean by "normal distance or size".

Comment: Normal as in pixel units. The size of a SURF keypoint is given in pixels, at least thats what I think.

Comment: Again - SURF matching has nothing common with size and pixels. At all.
I think, you are mixing two meaning of SURF keypoint. 
First - yours - is "circle in image with radius and coordinates of center". Second - used by knn-match is "DESCRIPTOR of corresponding circle". When you as a human compare two photos, you say about content similarity (is this both photo of cat, or no), not about physical size of the photoprints. The same story with knn-matching.